# how to remove node itself in NOT logical cypher query?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have this code in my method:

```
"match (n:" + query.getLabel() + " {" + propertiesGenerator(query.getNodeProperties()) + "}) ,(r:" + query.getLabel() + ")" +
                    "where NOT (n)-[:" + query.getRelation() + "{" + propertiesGenerator(query.getRelationProperties()) + "}]->(r)" +
                    "return r"
```

that it is equal to this cypher query in neo4j:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name:"salar"}),(r:Person)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:PARENT_OF {age:"20"}]->(r)
RETURN r
```

when i excute it , it return "a" node itself. in other words "a" dont have relation with itself.I dont want to return itself. how can i remove that?

Comment: Can't you add `AND NOT r=a`?

Comment: oh , thanks my friend. that's right. it is oooooooooooook.it worked.good luck